# Segmentation fault on login to mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu on my laptop (HP dv7, AMD Dual Core with 4 gigs RAM).  I am working on installing my development environment and tools and one of the first things I was working on is getting MySQL installed.

The following was my configure statement with options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-big-tables --with-unix-socket-path=/usr/local/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --with-named-curses-libs=/lib/libncurses.so.5.7
```

After I did the make;make install, I did the post configuration such as setting the root password and installing the mysqld daemon in its rightful place.

My issue is when I try to log in to mysql to start using it, the following shows what happens:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.1.42 Source distribution

Segmentation fault
```

I have searched Google extensively, I have searched through the mysql bugs database and I have yet to find anything that matches my issue.

Here is the contents of my my.cnf file, in case you want to see it:

```
$ cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
basedir=/usr/local/mysql
datadir=/usr/local/mysql
socket=/usr/local/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysql.server]
user=mysql
#basedir=/var/lib

[client]
socket=/usr/local/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
err-log=/usr/local/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I am really hoping that someone here can tell me what has gone wrong with my installation as I would really love to know.  I welcome and look forward to all responses.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use apt-get to install a package of the mysql binary that has been tested with your distro?

Comment: I have used binary distributions on all my other systems and on this one I wanted to go through the painstaking process of installing everything from source and include all the options that I want and are relevant to my system.  Granted, this is more specific to things like Apache and PHP's builds, but I just wanted to do it with MySQL as well.  Call me a masochist.

Comment: Fair enough.  Are you familiar with the 'ldd' command?  Try running it to check the library dependencies of your server daemon.

Comment: Ok, silly question.  What should I run ldd on?  In other words, how do I run it against the server daemon for mysql?  I tried it against /etc/init.d/mysql and it says it isn't a dynamic executable.  So, that's obviously the wrong thing to run it against.

Comment: Look in /usr/local/mysql/bin and you should see a file called 'mysqld'.  That is the server binary.

Comment: Ok, I ran it against the mysqld file from the source as it didn't exist with that name in the /usr/local/mysql/bin directory. When I ran  the 'ldd mysqld' command, it gave me a list and I verified that all but one of the libraries listed was on the system.  The one missing is 'linux-vdso.so.1'.  Will that library cause this?  

Also, back to the mysqld binary list, should there be a 'mysqld' file in /usr/local/mysql/bin or just the mysqld_safe file?

Comment: That's odd...generally when you specify a base directory of /usr/local/mysql the binaries get installed in a bin subdir.  But the file you checked was probably the one that was built during your compile.  Another way to find you server binary is to use the locate command (e.g. 'locate mysqld').  But yes, I would say that if you have an unmet library dependency that you should try to resolve it.  See if you can determine what rpm package provides that library and install it, and then restart mysql server, and try your client connection again.

Comment: I was looking around and it seems that library is something that is supposed to be provided by the kernel, but should not effect mysql's running.  

I have actually done a "make uninstall" and am installing it from apt-get, as you previously suggested.  The mysql piece is just a nice to try to compile from source part.  The important compilations will be apache and php, where I really do need to specify specifics that the binaries do not have.  I will post if the binaries work ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everyone know, I decided to back out my build and install mysql via apt-get in Ubuntu.  I was chatting with someone on the Ubuntu IRC and they highly recommended it.  I want to thank AJ for his help as I did learn to use ldd for the first time, but in the end, installing it via apt-get seemed plausible as I wasn't doing anything truly out of the ordinary that was not covered by the binary installation.

Thanks again for the help!

Regards,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

try adding **--disable-thread-safe-client** to your compile time options